# create standard compliant file

Tags: python, sed, awk, grep

I have a comma delimited file. The lines look like this...

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8
9,10
11,12,13,14,15
```

I need to have exactly 5 columns across all lines. So the new file will be...

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,,
9,10,,,
11,12,13,14,15
```

In other words, if there are less than 4 commas in a line. add required number to the end. I was told that there is python module that will do exactly the same. Where can I find such module? Is awk better suited for such type of tasks?

Comment: Don't reask questions if you don't get an answer please

Comment: The module is `csv`, although you'll probably need to pad the lists you read manually.

Comment: @Minion91 -- This isn't the same.  previously OP just wanted to skip malformed files.  This is asking about correcting them.

Comment: This is for some code challenge isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module you are looking for is the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). You'd still need to ensure that your lists meet you minimal length requirements:

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
    input = csv.reader(open('faultyfile.csv', 'rb'))
    output = csv.writer(output, dialect=input.dialect)
    for line in input:
        if len(line) < 5:
            line.extend([''] * (5 - len(line)))
        output.writerow(line)
```

Comment: If the data is pipe delimited | instead of , how to define it? Got it from the link. Thanks so much!

Comment: If I use delimiter='^' while reading, it does not use the same delimiter while writing (extend)? Ok in python things just works if you try it. got it.

Comment: the ouput csv.writer needs to be told what delimiter to use as well. I've updated the code slightly to configure the output csv.writer with the same dialect as the input reader.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using awk, then it is easy:

```
$ cat data.txt 
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8
9,10
11,12,13,14,15

$ awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' data.txt 
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,,
9,10,,,
11,12,13,14,15
```

Comment: awk has never stopped surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

```
def correct_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
         data = [ line[:-1]+(4-line.count(','))*',' + '\n' for line in f ]
    with open(fname,'w'):
         f.writelines(data)
```

As noted in the comments, this reads the entire file into memory when you really don't *need to*.  To do it not all in one go:

```
import shutil
def correct_file(fname):
    with open(fname,'r') as fin, open('temp','w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
           new = line[:-1]+(4-line.count(','))*',' + '\n'
           fout.write(new)
    shutil.move('temp',fname)
```

This will make any file named `temp` disappear in the current directory.  Of course, you can always use the `tempfile` module to get around that ...

---

And for the slightly more verbose, but bullet-proof (?) version:

```
import shutil
import tempfile
import atexit
import os

def try_delete(fname):
    try:
       os.unlink(fname)
    except OSError:
       if os.path.exists(fname):
          print "Couldn't delete existing file",fname

def correct_file(fname):
    with open(fname,'r') as fin, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w',delete=False) as fout:
        atexit.register(lambda f=fout.name: try_delete(f)) #Need a closure here ...
        for line in fin:
           new = line[:-1]+(4-line.count(','))*',' + '\n'
           fout.write(new)
    shutil.move(fout.name,fname) #This should get rid of the temporary file ...
```

Comment: why read everything into memory before writing out again? You can easily do this line by line. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Not if you want to avoid a `shutil.move` to move the temporary file.  I suppose you could use `tempfile` + `shutil` to create a temporary file safely and then move it, but if the file is small enough to fit into memory, why not just do it all in place?

Comment: And what would be the problem with that, really? How big are these files going to be?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- No problem with it.  It's just more complicated.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- The other advantage to doing it all in memory is that if the process is interrupted halfway through reading, you're not left with a half processed file on your disk.  I suppose that you could argue that if the process is interrupted halfway through writing, you've lost data ...

Comment: At which point having used a `tempfile` + `shutil.move` setup you get either a chance to restart when interrupted, or you have a complete conversion. Guaranteed. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- But you might not have any idea what the name of the `tempfile` *is*.  So you've lost the simple ability to delete it.  So...perhaps an `atexit.register` is in order to make sure we get rid of that file ;-).  Phew, doing this right is a bit tricky.

Comment: The `tempfile` module has various options to retain the filename, that's not a difficulty really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yes, but the file goes away when it gets *closed* (I think) if you use `delete=True`.  You can't `shutil.move` until *after you've closed* it due to buffering, etc, so you can't use `delete=True` here (I think).  Correct me if I'm wrong about this ... See my "bulletproof" version above, just for fun.  Any comments? (other than "use csv -- which might be a little too obvious).

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
      rows = []
      for line in f:
          rows.append(line.split(","))

max_cols = len(max(rows,key=len))
for row in rows:
    row.extend(['']*(max_cols-len(row))

print "\n".join(str(r) for r in rows)
```

If you are sure that it will always be n items long (in this case 5) and you will always know before opening the file ... it is more memory efficient to do (something like this)

```
 with open("f1","r"):
      with open("f2","w"):
          for line in f1:
              f2.write(line+(","*(4-line.count(",")))+"\n")
```

Comment: why read everything into memory before writing out again? You can easily do this line by line. :-)

Comment: well only cause he says its always five... this takes into account that there might be 6 or 7 in some file...

Comment: also a good point by you ... assuming it is always 5 and you always know this before looking at the file :)

Comment: `list(line.split(','))` is redundant.  Also, why not use a listcomp?  `rows = [ line.split(',') for line in f ]`?

Comment: Also, with your second example, you need to be careful with newlines.  `line` will contain a trailing newline and then you write something *without* a trailing newline.

Comment: oh yeah good call ... on both cases... for some reason I was thinking split returned a tuple ... I was trying to be verbose mostly (as to why no list comp) (besides you demonstrate a list comp. example :P)

Comment: My final comment, `print "\n".join([str(r) ... ])` -- You can omit the square brackets and just use a generator.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed ':a;s/,/&/4;t;s/$/,/;ta' file
```